# using loader in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have multiple QML files. I just want to link them. Then I want to return to my home page from every page I navigate to. I am using loader in every page
Here is my code.

```
import QtQuick 1.1
Rectangle{
    id:welcome
    width:480
    height:272
    Loader{
        id:loader
        focus:false
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "light blue" }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "blue" }
    }
    Text{
        text:"\n\t\tPRESS ENTER"
        font.bold:true
        font.pointSize: 17
    }
    Button {
    id: wel
        height:30;
        x:parent.width/2-30
        y:parent.height/2-30
        focus:true
        border.color:"black"
        opacity: activeFocus ? 1.0 : 0.5
        Text{   
            text:"WELCOME"
            anchors.horizontalCenter:wel.horizontalCenter;
            anchors.verticalCenter:wel.verticalCenter;
        }   
        Keys.onReturnPressed: {
            wel.focus=false
            loader.focus=true;
            anchors.fill=parent
           loader.source="Home.qml";
            //welcome.visible=false;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whenever I click on the button its loading new file. But the welcome page will not go. Both the file's will be overlapped. When I did visible=false complete UI will go. I get a white screen.
Can any one help me fix this problem? 
How to load other file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load multiple pages you will need to use [Connections](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qml-connections.html) element to handle signal from the page you have loaded.

```
Loader {
    id: windowLoader
    source: "Welcome.qml"
    focus: true

    property bool valid: item !== null
}
Button {
    Keys.onReturnPressed: {
        windowLoader.source = "Page1.qml"
    }
}
Connections {
    ignoreUnknownSignals: true
    target: windowLoader.valid? windowLoader.item : null
    onChangeToPage2: { windowLoader.source = "Page2.qml" }
    onPageExit: { windowLoader.source = "Welcome.qml" }
}
```

And from the pages you load you will need to emit the "changeToPage2" and "pageExit" [signals](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/qmlevents.html). The emitted signals will be handled by the Connections element.

Page1.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: page1
    signal changeToPage2
    signal pageExit
    Button {
        id: exitButton
        Keys.onReturnPressed: { page1.pageExit() }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did whatever u suggested. some what its improved. but in each loading page one gets faded and at last it gets vanished.. and also dat welcome text and the text inside the button will be visible in every view :(

Comment: The z order of items depends on the sequence in which you specify them. Place the Loader after the Button in the code, or set the z value of the Loader to a larger value, then the new page should be over the buttons.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. If you need to have the Button visible in only the first page, you should just create your button in you Welcome page. And load Welcome.qml from Main.qml, where Main.qml has no buttons, just the Loader.